# How do I convert this code so it can be used in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda

I Have a simple pong project I have created in Monogame with a very simple impementation of a decision Tree.

Now I'm trying to create the same game, with the same logic in unity instead.

My nodes in the Dt is structured like this:

```
public DecisionTreeNode DecisionTreeAction(PaddleAI AI_Ball)
    {
        DecisionTreeNode rootnode = new DecisionTreeNode
        {
            TestFunction = (BallControls) => AI_Ball.StayAtSamePosition(),
            Yes = new Decision { evaluatedData = true },
            No = new Decision { evaluatedData = false }
        };

        DecisionTreeNode Stay = new DecisionTreeNode
        {
            TestFunction = (BallControls) => AI_Ball.StayAtSamePosition(),
            Yes = new Decision { evaluatedData = true },
            No = new Decision { evaluatedData = false }
        };

        DecisionTreeNode GoUp = new DecisionTreeNode
        {
            TestFunction = (BallControls) => AI_Ball.GoUP(),
            Yes = new Decision { evaluatedData = true },
            No = new Decision { evaluatedData = false }
        };
```

And etc with the rest.

Unity does not use the new keyword as in monogame.
How can I re-write these expressions, so that they can be used in Unity?

DecisionTreeNode is a class.
BallControls is a class for the balls logic.
Paddle_AI is a class with the move functions for the AI paddle.

TestFunction is this:

```
public Func<BallControls, bool> TestFunction { get; set; }
```

Comment: Of course you can use `new` in Unity too. What's the problem you're facing here?

Comment: `new` is a general `c#` keyword ... Unity can't forbid it ... you only can not use it to create `MonoBehaviour` instances and some other `UnityEngine.Object` class types ...

Comment: Alright, I see. It is because the classes I create are monobehaviour that I get some errors. Thank you @derHugo

Comment: Do those `Decision` nodes really have to be `MonoBehaviour`? `MonoBehaviour` makes only sense if you have a `GameObject` in the scene related to it .. for a pure data class it makes no sense / is unnecessary

Comment: I understand. No it does not. I realized that both Decision and DecisionTreeNode didnt needed monobehaviour. @derHugo